# Why I can't execute .php from different Pc?

Tags: php, html, network-programming

I want to execute PHP from another PC?

This is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form id="form1" target="_blank" method="post" action="192.168.18.131/myphp/test2.php">
<input type="text">
<input type="button" onclick="this.disabled=true;document.getElementById('form1').submit();" value="Button">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

It doesn't create new tab.

Comment: if writing 192.168.18.131/myphp/test2.php  on the browser you have an output for test2.php

Comment: Yes it has. I use ubuntu for test

Comment: Stick `http://` in front of the `192.168.18.131`. Because `192.168.18.131` is not a local path of the host serving that html.

Comment: Wow It's work just Stick http:// in front of the 192.168.18.131 thank you for all of you.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the formaction attribute for your input.

Here's a link:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_formaction.asp

Also your text input needs a name if you want to retrieve a value from it.